# Computing ring class field from ray class field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$ be any imaginary quadratic field. Let $O_{\mathcal{K}}$ be its maximal order and $O$ be any order. Let $m$ be the conductor of $K$.
Is it possible to compute ring class field from ray class field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to my answer at the following  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803837/152394; which gives the idea of what an ring class field and ray class field is